# Mysql increment value on multiple cases to order by

Tags: mysql

I have a table with products, and by answering a set of questions (Could be 2 or could be six, it's not always the same) I want to get results. Each answer has rules to it like `color = green` or `noise > 69`.

Now I don't want to use these rules as a `WHERE` to refine my searchresults, but I want to increment a variable on `CASE` so I can `ORDER` on the amount of true conditions. I still get all values, but the ones that better suit my customers needs are on top.

I tried a lot already, something like: 
`SELECT a.*, b.*,COUNT(CASE WHEN (b.noise >= 1600) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as condition_true`

But I cant get it to work with multiple CASES.

SAMPLE DATA:

Products table:

```
id    |    title
1     |    washing machine X
2     |    Washing Machine Y200
3     |    Even cooler washing machine
```

Productinfo table

```
id    |    noise    |    color    |    locked    | product_id
1     |    40       |    white    |    1         | 1
2     |    68       |    green    |    0         | 2
3     |    72       |    green    |    1         | 3
```

Possible rules I will use in the output table

- b.noise > 42
- b.color = "green"
- b.locked = 1

I would love an output table like this

```
product_id    |    title                          |    condition_true
3             |    Even cooler washing machine    |    3  
2             |    Washing Machine Y200           |    2 
1             |    washing machine X              |    1
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ok, I will do that now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` only returns one value, and `COUNT` requires multiple rows. You could just add them.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, (CASE WHEN b.noise >= 1600 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                 (CASE WHEN color = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS relevance
FROM table1
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Or, abbreviated for MySQL:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, (b.noise >= 1600) +
                 (color = 'green') AS relevance
FROM table1
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly the thing I needed. Just add em. I'm gonna blow my stupid head off. :)

Comment: @MarcusAdams . . . If you are going to abbreviate for MySQL, just use `( (b.noise >= 1600) + (color = 'green') ) as relevance`.

Comment: Good suggestion. Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` is not what you want, that works to aggregate results from multiple rows when using `GROUP BY`.

I would do this using a series of `IF() statements`, returning `1` or `0` based on the condition (you could also return a bigger number, for more important columns or something):

```
SELECT IF(b.noise >= 1600,1,0)+IF(b.ocl1 <= 3,1,0)+...;
```